# Xamarin HMS Push Kit, notification message, parameter "foreground_show" is ignored?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

According to official Huawei docs, "You can set the message.android.notification.foreground_show field to make notification messages not displayed by NC. In this case, when your app is running in the foreground, the notification messages are transparently transmitted to your app, and processed and displayed by your app."

Sample code:

```
{
"message": {
    "notification": {
        "title": "message title",
        "body": "message body"
    },
    "android": {
        "notification": {
            "foreground_show": false,
            "click_action": {
                "type": 1,
                "action": "com.huawei.codelabpush.intent.action.test"
            }
        }
    },
    "token": [
        "pushtoken1"
    ]
}
```

}

I have a problem with this parameter, it seems it's just ignored. I've created a message service that implements HmsMessageService class, then have overridden its OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) method.

My app succesfully obtains access tokens from server, receives data messages when in foreground, my device receives notification messages when app killed or in background and then starts an app on user tap, but I still can't intercept notification messages when app is in foreground.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement **IHmsPushEvent** interface to your Activity or you cannot listen events. This interfaces's functions provides the listening HmsPush events.

**Solution:**

1. Implement **IHmsPushEvent** interface to Activity.
2. Configure **OnMessageReceived** method.
3. Remote Message will be received, after you send the notification.
4. Use **GetNotification** method to get notification data.

**Sample Code:**

```
        public void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            string MethodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            RemoteMessage.Notification notification = message.GetNotification();
            Log.Info(MethodName,$"Title: {notification.Title}\nBody:{notification.Body}");
        }
```

For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/hmspushevent-0000001055880201-V1?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: I've found the real reason :)

I forgot to delete sample modules from xamarin-push-package-5.0.2.300 source files before compiling Xamarin Android libraries. And XamarinHmsPushDemo.Hmssample class intercepted my messages :)

Mea culpa, mea maxima culpa :)

But thank you anyway, your answer helped me to dive into Push Kit modules deeper :)